# 50% core utilization on mingw32-make -j enabled

Tags: c++, build, mingw, cpu

My first post here, but I found a lot of answers regarding C++ and Qt, thanks!

When compiling my Qt Project with mingw32-maxe.exe I only reach 50% of cpu utilization (the Task Manager shows 50% on all 8 diagrams (i7) ), I already tried using -j, -j8, -j9 and -j16 but nothing changes.

Also my CPU never reaches the 2.4GHz (probably due to the low utilization of 50%). My energy-saving settings in Win are set to "Höchstleistung" (Maximum Performance), I checked the minimum CPU-Frequency Mark, it is 100% on Battery and AC, but the Cpu always stays at 1.2 GHz.

I noticed this issue after upgrading to Win 8.1 (I didnt notice it immediately, so im not sure it is Win 8.1) but 1 month ago all cores ran at 100%.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Does your project have enough source files so it could even reach 100% cpu?

Comment: @Thomas Yes it has about 30 cpp-Files, included the moc_files.

Comment: Maybe you want to try http://stackoverflow.com/a/9421570/1392778

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED!

On my Samsung laptop the "silent" option was switched on in the settings app, this reduces the CPU power regardless of the current Windows energy-saving options. Setting the option to off solved my problem.

Thanks anyway for all contributions!