# wxwidget compilation failing with mingw

Tags: mingw, wxwidgets

I am compiling wxWidgets-3.1.0 with below command :

```
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.0\build\msw>mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc
if not exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\mswud mkdir ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\mswud
gcc -c -o gcc_mswud\wxtiff_tif_win32.o -g -O0 -mthreads  -DHAVE_W32API_H -DNDEBUG -I..\..\src\zlib -I..\..\src\jpeg -I..\..\src\tiff\libtiff   -MTgcc_mswud\wxtiff_tif_win32.o -MFgcc_mswud\wxtiff_tif_win32.o.d -MD -MP ../../src/tiff/libtiff/tif_win32.c
In file included from ../../src/tiff/libtiff/tiffio.h:257:0,
                from ../../src/tiff/libtiff/tiffiop.h:59,
                from ../../src/tiff/libtiff/tif_win32.c:30:
c:\mingw\include\stdio.h:345:12: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '__mingw__snprintf'
extern int __mingw_stdio_redirect__(snprintf)(char*, size_t, const char*, ...);
            ^
makefile.gcc:6018: recipe for target 'gcc_mswud\wxtiff_tif_win32.o' failed
mingw32-make: *** [gcc_mswud\wxtiff_tif_win32.o] Error 1
```

I looked the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35830478/cant-build-the-new-wxwidgets-what-should-i-do) for solution, that is not helping.

Followed [this](http://codelite.org/Developers/BuildingWxWidgetsWin#toc3) also, but getting different errors :

```
c:\mingw\include\stdio.h:345:12: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '__mingw__snprintf'
extern int __mingw_stdio_red.oirect]);_
            ^
E_(snprintf)(char*, size_t, const char*, ...);
            ^
rror 1
mingw32-make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Makefile.gcc:6024: recipe for target 'gcc_mswudll\wxtiff_tif_close.o' failed
mingw32-make: *** [gcc_mswudll\wxtiff_tif_close.o] Error 1
Makefile.gcc:6027: recipe for target 'gcc_mswudll\wxtiff_tif_codec.o' failed
mingw32-make: *** [gcc_mswudll\wxtiff_tif_codec.o] Error 1
Makefile.gcc:6030: recipe for target 'gcc_mswudll\wxtiff_tif_color.o' failed
mingw32-make: *** [gcc_mswudll\wxtiff_tif_color.o] Error 1
Makefile.gcc:6033: recipe for target 'gcc_mswudll\wxtiff_tif_compress.o' failed
mingw32-make: *** [gcc_mswudll\wxtiff_tif_compress.o] Error 1
Makefile.gcc:6018: recipe for target 'gcc_mswudll\wxtiff_tif_win32.o' failed
mingw32-make: *** [gcc_mswudll\wxtiff_tif_win32.o] Error 1
In file included from ../../src/tiff/Mlaikbtiffe/tiffio.h:257:0,
f                 fromi le.gcc:6036.:. recipe for target 'gcc_mswudll\wxtiff_tif_dir.o' faile/d
../srcm/tiff/libtiff/tiffiopi.h:59,
n           g     fromw ../../src/t3iff/libtiff/tif_dirinfo.c:31:
c2:\mi-ngw\include\stdio.h:345:12: error: expected 'm=', ','a, ';', 'kasme' o:r '__attribute__' before ' __m*ing*w__*snp rint[f'
extern int __mingw_stdio_redirect__(snprintf)(char*, size_t, const char*, ...);
            ^
_mswudll\wxtiff_tif_dir.o] Error 1
Makefile.gcc:6039: recipe for target 'gcc_mswudll\wxtiff_tif_dirinfo.o' failed
mingw32-make: *** [gcc_mswudll\wxtiff_tif_dirinfo.o] Error 1
```

I have set environment variables for

```
WXCFG=C:\wxWidgets-3.1.0\lib\gcc_dll\mswu
WXWIN=C:\wxWidgets-3.1.0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your running into the issue described [here](https://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/17936).

You can either

1. Apply the patch from [here](https://github.com/wxWidgets/libtiff/commit/b99ec334ff604db08ce258934271dde7b7bef4af) to fix the issue.
2. Use the latest version of wxWidgets from git, since the issue has been fixed there.
3. Use a version of MinGW from either MSYS2 or MinGW64.  Although if you go that route, be sure to use the latest release because those versions of MinGW has a different problem (at least for some configurations of wxWidgets) until very recently.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped, but now I am getting other error `makefile.gcc:14210: recipe for target 'gcc_mswud\corelib_app.o' failed
mingw32-make: *** [gcc_mswud\corelib_app.o] Error 1`

Comment: Finally I am able to compile Wxwidget after downloading mingw-w64, thanks a lot :)